# "If the concentration of the drug in the (a?) sample does not exceed.." - an article usage question

Tags: articles

The very first sentence in a document section titled "Preparation of Solutions":

> If the concentration of the drug in **a (the?)** sample does not exceed 1.0 mg/ml, transfer 500 µl of the sample into a 1.5 ml microtube, add 200 µl of sample dilution solution 7 and mix (test solution).

Should one use **a** or **the** with **sample**? I think that since the implied meaning is "the sample that you have chosen for the preparation of your test solution", it should be **the**.

But maybe **a** is also acceptable? It might be read as "in **any** sample that you choose for the preparation of your test solution".

The sample was not mentioned previously in the document.

Comment: We'd need the prior context. Either **a** or **the** could work here. But since "the" is used in the "transfer 500..." clause, I'd go for "a", agreeing with your understanding of "any".   "If the concentration .... in a (any) sample does not exceed ... transfer  500 ... of the sample into...."

Comment: @TRomano - this is the very first sentence in the section, so there is little prior context.

Comment: Since there is no prior context, the indefinite article must be used. The clause then establishes the context for the rest of the sentence, and licences the use of the definite article. The question might have been worded better as "In any sample, if the concentration of the drug does not exceed..." Of course, the same question arises as to which article to use for "drug", and the answer is "more context needed".

Comment: Are we speaking about a certain sample or just any sample? Both are acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the concentration of the drug in **(a/the) sample** does not exceed 1.0 mg/ml, transfer 500 µl of **the sample** into a 1.5 ml microtube, add 200 µl of sample dilution solution 7 and mix (test solution).

In this situation I would prefer "the" sample because you are referring back to it later in the sentence. It is a specific sample even though it hasn't been mentioned before.

The indefinite article can be appropriate though if you were talking about a generic sample, for example:

> If the concentration of the drug in **a sample** does not exceed 1.0 mg/ml, no further dilution is necessary.

After thinking about it, I think you could refer back to it and still use the indefinite article if you changed the way you refer to it.

> If the concentration of the drug in **a sample** does not exceed 1.0 mg/ml, transfer 500 µl of **it** into a 1.5 ml microtube...

This is a less formal option, but I thought it was worth mentioning. The sample is a generic one until it passes the condition in the "if" and then it becomes specific enough that we know what "it" means. You might also write:

> If the concentration of the drug in **a sample** does not exceed 1.0 mg/ml, transfer 500 µl of **that sample** into a 1.5 ml microtube...

but it seems a little awkward to me.

Answer (score 3):

Since no sample was mentioned previously, there is nothing for "the sample" to refer to. "A sample" means any old sample. "The sample" means the previously mentioned sample. So first, "a sample" to mean some sample, then "the sample" to refer to that same sample.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a great rant from a friend I went to school with:

> First I pick up **a** banana. Then I cut **the** banana. Why does cutting it go from **a** to **the**???

The **a** suggests we select the item from among many or we have encountered one for the first time, whereas **the** references a previously encountered object.

However, these are technical instructions and you should be more concise:

> If the concentration of the drug does not exceed 1.0 mg/ml, transfer 500 µl into a 1.5 ml microtube, add 200 µl of Dilution Solution 7, mix, and then test the resulting solution.

Comment: Your rewording is more concise, but it leaves out critical information, i.e. what you are transferring into the microtube. You assume that "the drug" is the same as "the sample" which isn't necessarily correct. The sample could be a blood sample that has the drug in it. Also my interpretation of (test solution) is that it's not a directive, it's a description of the solution you just made from the sample.